# Regex Pattern for text combined in two tags

Tags: html, regex, web-scraping

I need a regex or a way to extract this information:

> "Per chi ha poche pretese 18 dicembre 2014"

from this HTML string:

> <b>Per chi ha poche pretese</b>, <nobr>18 dicembre
>   2014</nobr>

I need to do it while scraping an entire HTML page where the pattern
could be repeated 2-3 times in the content...

Is it possible with REGEX ?

Thanks
Dario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you: `<b>(.*?)<\/b>, <nobr>(.*?)<\/nobr>`

You can test it [over here](https://regex101.com/r/ieHq2i/3)

**The matches will be:**

- First index will be the the string from `b`
- Second index will be the string from `nobr`

Just loop over the results and concatenate indexes 1 + 2 for the full sentence.

P.S: Of course you should add the `global` flag as well

Comment: Hi and Arieljannai and tank you very much for your precius support.
I think we are close to a solution.
Have a look there: https://regex101.com/r/ieHq2i/2
As u can see, the regex u provide me catch 14 occurence. It works also with DIV but I only need to search using "b" and "nobr" tags...

Comment: np, just change it to: `<(b|nobr)>(.*?)<\/\1>`

Comment: I've updated my answer with the regex that matches only `b` and `nobr`

Comment: Thanks bro, we have made one step ahed but actually it finds 11 matches now while it should find only 3 matches...
You can identify the 3 matches I want to get by searching simple text "</b>, <nobr>" in the example html page code I provided.

Comment: Can you mention which of the parts should be matched?

Comment: How about `<(b|nobr)>([^<].*?)<\/\1>`? It matches only `b` and `nobr` and when there's no another opening tag right after

Comment: Last regex now find 7 matches, the 3 parts that I need to match are:
"<b>prodotto scadente</b>, <nobr>1 settembre 2016</nobr>" ,    "<b>Per chi ha poche pretese</b>, <nobr>18 dicembre 2014</nobr>"   and "<b>DOPO UN GIORNO DI UTILIZZO GI&agrave; CONTAMINA I CIBI</b>, <nobr>15 febbraio 2016</nobr>"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136253/discussion-between-arieljannai-and-darion1).